# Lotus notes plugin: save email to eml file

Tags: c++, lotus-notes

Within a C++ Lotus Notes plugin, I want to save the current email (represented by hNote HANDLE) to .eml file. I browsed through the documentation, and found the function NSFNoteExtractFile which saves the given item (represented as BLOCKID) to a file. but how do I convert the hNote HANDLE to BLOCKID item in order to save it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a note handle into a BLOCKID. A BLOCKID is associated with an item inside a note, not with the note itself. NSFNoteExtractFile extracts a file attachment from a note, it does not convert a note into a file. I.e., if you have a mail message with an attached .doc file, you would use NSFItemInfo to get the BLOCKID of the $FILE item within the note that represents the .doc file, and then you would use NSFNoteExtractFile to save the .doc file (and only the .doc file) as a seaparate disk file.

To the best of my knowledge, there is still no API from IBM Lotus to do what you want. There is a Java API to convert message content to MIME format, but you have to provide all the code for generating and formatting the message headers. That's reasonably easy to do in Java, but in C++ you may have to provide a lot of the logic yourself. Here's a link to a blog post by Bob Balaban that includes sample C# code doing the same thing, and since there's no equivalent of the Java convertToMIME API call in the Lotus COM classes that he uses in C#, he includes code that calls from C# into C, so that will show you which APIs you will need to use for converting the content in C++.

Comment: Here it the link Richard refers to: http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/geek-o-terica-15-easy-conversion-of-notes-documents-to-mime-format-part-1